# Disable Safari top result in Spotlight

Tags: macos, spotlight, big-sur

Since Big Sur, for absolutely anything I put into spotlight, the top result and the selected-by-default result is Safari.

[image]

How do I get rid of this row entirely? Or, skip it to select the second row by default.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove Safari suggestions in Spotlight. I would suggest you [rebuild the index](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716) first to see if that will resolve the issue of other results not showing up first.